# Templates in TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.x

I use TYPO3 v7.6.2!
Create a custom extension. 
As the controller can select a template to generate? After the default, select the name_template = name_action.

Comment: Ahm... and what exactly is your problem?!

Comment: "name_template = name_action" means you want different view for your action? or if you can describe more about your question then others can helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I found the answer to my question.
In order to use different templates for the same extension, you just need to adjust the way in typoscript path to resources on the page where you need to.

Constants:

```
plugin.tx_plugin {
  view {
    templateRootPath = fileadmin/tx_plugin/you_custom_template
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/tx_plugin/you_custom_partial
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/tx_plugin/you_custom_layout
  }
}
```

and setup:

```
plugin.tx_plugin  {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = {$plugin.tx_plugin.view.templateRootPath}
    partialRootPaths.0 = {$plugin.tx_plugin.view.partialRootPath}
    layoutRootPaths.0 = {$plugin.tx_plugin.view.layoutRootPath}
  }
}
```

Comment: can you mark your solution as correct answer, thanks!